# same confirmation dialog box but different message

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Is there a way on how to use the same code for the confirmation message but the message is different? I just want to reuse the existing code and change only the message instead of creating another function. Is it possible?

```html
<p-dialog [(visible)]="openDialogBox1" [style]="{ width: '50vw' }" modal="true" [closable]="false">
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
<h3>Confirm ABC?</h3>
</ng-template>
<p>Are you sure you want to tag as ABC?</p>
</p-dialog>

<p-dialog [(visible)]="openDialogBox2" [style]="{ width: '50vw' }" modal="true" [closable]="false">
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
<h3>Confirm include the company?</h3>
</ng-template>
<p>Are you sure you want to inlcude the company? This will include the sub unit.</p>
</p-dialog>
```

Answer (score 4):

Make the Dialogbox as Reusable component.

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="openDialogBox" [style]="{ width: '50vw' }" 
modal="true" [closable]="false">
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
<h3>{{ messageHeader }}</h3>
</ng-template>
<p>{{ messageBody }}</p>
</p-dialog>
```

Add the following variables in your ts file of the corresponding component.

```
@Input() messageHeader!: string;
@Input() messageBody!: string;
```

Use the component as below where ever you need.

```
<app-component-name [messageHeader] = "content" [messageBody] = "content"></app-component-name>
```